# Beginner question - the syntax of objects used in Django

Tags: django, syntax

i am wondering if the below code is valid as there is no method assigned after objects. However it seem to be working in my code. How is this happened as "create" is only a part of my own defined method (create_user), the computer shouldn't understand my method as it is not a build-in method

```
def create_user(self, username, email, password):

    new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    new_user.save()
```

is the string "create" work in some way? or "objects" will create database in the absence of assigned method by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#manager-names):

> By default, Django adds a `Manager` with the name `objects` to every Django model class.

Comment: which mean "objects" will create database in the absence of assigned method by default? thanks..

Comment: @chow: ... I will be perfectly honest here. I cannot understand a *single thing* you are saying.

Comment: i guess i understood now, i mixed up the use of "models" vs "objects", that's why i thought it would create a database originally.....really thanks!!!